# Can user can be grant select on the specified database rather than the specified table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

Can User can be grant select on the specified database rather than the specified table in oracle? How to write the query? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about schemas on the same Oracle server. Answer is no, you need to grant access for each table in another schema. (NOTE: There is SELECT ANY but that is not a good path - it is for all schemas. It is not good because of security reasons)